# <base href="/" /> in local server

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

My angular project is running on http : //localhost:8080/MyAngular/
I have added `<base href="/">` to remove hashbang. But when i click on help link it is considering path as http: //localhost:8080/help instead of http: //localhost:8080/MyAngular/help

Please help me in configuring this correctly. I have tried `<base href="/MyAngular">` and `<base href="./">` still the issue is not resolved.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Shouldn't base href be /MyAngular/ ?

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions Madan?

Comment: I have tried the solution that u have suggeested but it didn't worked